# Resolve unfound entry points on Windows 11 C++ app deployed on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, sdk, windows-11

I would like to develop a Windows program with a feature available in The Windows SDK (10.0.22621) for Windows 11, version 22H2 using visual studio 2022 17.0.11.

However my development machine and deployment environments are still on Windows 10.
Installation of the SDK, and compilation/linking of the code succeeds, execution fails due to "unfound procedure entry points"

With earlier Windows version an upgrade of the Windows CRT was possible through a local installation of the universal c runtime. How can I execute the program (without upgrading to Windows 11)?

Comment: Install a Windows 11 Virtual Machine. The VM host is built into WIndows 10, then grab a Windows ISO image from MS and install it into the VM, skip the licencing. Next setup cross-machine debugging from MSVS on your development Windows 10 into the Windows 11 client VM.

Comment: The runtime is probably not the problem, it's that the application is using APIs only available in Windows 11.  If so installing an updated Runtime Support cannot fix the problem of OS not having the missing entry points.  Another option rather than a VM is a second computer running WIndows 11 and cross-debugging to that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the distinction between the c runtime and windows API. I was not aware that updating the SDK to the latest version would make it impossible to run the app on Windows 10. I'll stick with the latest Windows 10 SDK version 2104 (10.0.20348.0) then.